# How can I start a function automatically after a certain period of time?

Tags: pallet, upgrade

I want to start a function automatically after a certain *period* of time in our chain. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `pallet-scheduler`.

```rust
pallet_scheduler::Pallet::<T>::schedule(
     Origin::root(), // Depending on what you have configured as `ScheduleOrigin` in the runtime for scheduler
     when,
     None, // or Some if it should be periodic
     priority,
     Box::new(Call::Whatever {}), // The actual call that should be scheduled
);
```

You can also program this on your own using `on_initialize`:

```rust
fn on_initialize(now: T::BlockNumber) -> Weight {
    if now == expected_number {
        // do whatever you want to do.
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, you were faster 

Comment: @bkchr Can you please suggest the resources to learn about Hooks?

Answer (score 2):

There exists the `scheduler` pallet which archives this. The downside is that only the `ScheduleOrigin` may schedule calls. But your question does not state who should be able to schedule calls.
The signature looks like this:

```rust
pub fn schedule(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    when: T::BlockNumber,
    maybe_periodic: Option<schedule::Period<T::BlockNumber>>,
    priority: schedule::Priority,
    call: Box<CallOrHashOf<T>>,
) -> DispatchResult {
```

The call may be executed by the scheduler at any block after `when`, giving no guarantees *if* it ever happens. Reasons for non-execution could be full blocks, full schedules or an over-weight call. On successful execution a `Dispatched` event will be emitted for your convenience.

Usage in tests looks like this:

```rust
// Some example call to be scheduled.
let call = Box::new(RuntimeCall::Logger(LoggerCall::log {
    i: 69,
    weight: Weight::from_ref_time(10),
}));
assert_ok!(Scheduler::schedule(RuntimeOrigin::root(), 4, None, 127, call));
```

Another way would be to write a pallet and utilize its `on_initialize`/`on_idle` hooks. In these hooks you can then check the block number and run a specific task. The `scheduler` uses the same mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Like @bkchr mentioned, you can use `on_initialize` hook.
Here is a concrete example in the treasury pallet:

```rust
    impl<T: Config<I>, I: 'static> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T, I> {
        fn on_initialize(n: T::BlockNumber) -> Weight {
            // Check to see if we should spend some funds!
            if (n % T::SpendPeriod::get()).is_zero() {
                Self::spend_funds()
            } else {
                Weight::zero()
            }
        }
    }
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/d11dd02dda6a00800a13cd59a0c2f07ac75e082d/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L309-L326

`spend_funds()` is only called on the `T::SpendPeriod::get()` - which in Polkadot's case, is every 24 days.

Comment: can please suggest any resources to learn more about hooks?

Comment: Yes, you can look here: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/trait.Hooks.html and you can also do a search in the Substrate repo for specific hooks - they are used extensively.